# create number of posts equal to a specific interger

Tags: php

I am calling an interger value ($number) from a query, eg $number = 50; 
I would then like to create the same amount of posts as the interger value eg create 50 posts. 
The post name will be $post_name = $title_$number;

What php function can I use to create the number of posts equal to the interger value?

```
for ($i = 1, $i++, $i = $number){
//create new post
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $post_title_$i             
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_id =  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

Comment: for loop with the ending limit as the integer and the code for creating post inside it

Comment: I tried the code above but it only gave me one post ending the 2. How do I get all the posts, say 50 if $number = 50?

Comment: your for loop is incorrect  and if you're using wordpress then the procedure can be different..so please confirm if you're project is on wordpres or not

Comment: yes I'm using wordpress, I'm sorry if that as unclear

Comment: sorry I have not worked with wordpress much

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (range(1, $max_number) as $number){
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $post_title_$number             
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_id =  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```